# Error installing mu editor on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, python

I cannot install mu editor on ubuntu. Below I'll copy what it says. I tried a lot of things and maybe I screwed everything up

```
-PC:~$ pip3 install mu-editor
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mu-editor
  Using cached mu_editor-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting qtconsole==4.3.1
  Using cached qtconsole-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Collecting semver>=2.8.0
  Downloading semver-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle==2.4.0
  Using cached pycodestyle-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting pyserial==3.4
  Downloading pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (193 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 193 kB 175 kB/s 
Collecting mu-editor
  Using cached mu_editor-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting requests>=2.19.1
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting gpiozero>=1.4.1
  Downloading gpiozero-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 148 kB 86 kB/s 
Collecting pyflakes==2.0.0
  Downloading pyflakes-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 53 kB 72 kB/s 
Collecting guizero>=0.5.2
  Downloading guizero-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42 kB 54 kB/s 
Collecting pigpio>=1.40.post1
  Downloading pigpio-1.78-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting mu-editor
  Using cached mu_editor-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
  Using cached mu_editor-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
ERROR: Cannot install mu-editor==1.0.0, mu-editor==1.0.1, mu-editor==1.0.2 and mu-editor==1.0.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    mu-editor 1.0.3 depends on qscintilla==2.11.4
    mu-editor 1.0.2 depends on PyQtChart==5.11.3
    mu-editor 1.0.1 depends on qscintilla==2.10.7
    mu-editor 1.0.0 depends on qscintilla==2.10.7

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

You have library version conflict.

On my 18.04 LTS system with all packages from official repositories (python3@3.6.9, pip3@9.0.1) I have installed `mu-editor` normally by adjusting Python3 package versions using the following command:

```
pip3 install --user qscintilla==2.10 PyQtChart==5.9.2 pyqt5==5.9.2 mu-editor==1.0.3
```

If you use the same python3 version but with upgraded pip3@21.1.2 you can use installation command below:

```
pip3 install --user qscintilla==2.11.4 mu-editor==1.0.3
```

---

Please note that `mu-editor` [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mu-editor) is presented in official Ubuntu repositories only since 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I've tried what you said but I've got the following error:

yadira@yadira-PC:~$ pip3 install --user qscintilla==2.10 PyQtCHart==5.9.2 pyqt5==5.9.2 mu-editor
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qscintilla==2.10 (from versions: 2.12.0, 2.12.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qscintilla==2.10

Comment: It seems that we have different versions of pip3 and/or python3. My system has pip3 from official repository with version 9.0.1 and Python3 from official repository with version 3.6.9. At first try updated answer. If it fails - then please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341365/edit) your question and add the following information to it: `which pip3; pip3 --version; which python3; python3 --version;`.